# Qt has removed version 5.5?

Tags: qt, deprecated, qt5.5

Yesterday I was wondering why http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.5/5.5.1/ was giving a 404. Then I checked about 10 mirrors for it - and they also were all 404?

So I thought just their server is down or something (why would mirrors be affected?). But now today, http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.5/5.5.1/ still does not exist, yet some really old versions (1.x) and other versions (5.1 and 5.9 for example) exist at http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/

I haven't seen any announcements about Qt deprecating version 5.5. Has it been taken down permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now under http://download.qt.io/new_archive/qt/ which is not mirrored - it was done due to some mirrors had problems hosting all Qt versions.